# How to compute the following exclude an index summation in R?

Tags: r

If we have a dataset `x_{ij}` of size 4 by 3 and a vector `y_{i}` of size 4 by 1.

```
  a1=c(1,2,3, 4)
  a2=c(4,5,6, 7)
  a3=c(7,8,9,10)
  x <- cbind(a1, a2, a3)
  y <- c(1,5,7,9)
```

I want to compute the summation of `sum_{i}y_{i}-sum_{i}(sum_{l\neq j}x_{il})`. For example, if in my for loop of `j`,

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by `sum_{i}y_{i}-sum_{i}(sum_{l\neq j}x_{il})`

Comment: *"but this does work"* ... is that supposed to be "does not work"? Please include literal errors and expected output given this sample data.

Comment: @stevec Please see my image in the question. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrWkf.jpg

Comment: @r2evans Not an error but this result is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a1=c(1,2,3, 4)
a2=c(4,5,6, 7)
a3=c(7,8,9,10)
x <- cbind(a1, a2, a3)
y <- c(1,5,7,9)
n <- NULL
for(j in 1:ncol(x)) n[j] <- sum(y)-sum(x[-j]) 
n
```

Comment: For `j=1`, this is sum_{i}y_{i}-(x_12+x_22+x_32+x_42+x_13+x_23+x_33+x_43)? Your results seems different from this one.

Comment: I wrote the formula in the Latex. Please see the image in my question.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, can you help me see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020183/how-to-compute-this-summation-in-r? Thanks.